# Annotate that a class method used in the constructor instantiates some class members

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, suppress-warnings

I have a class with constructors that share part of the initialization procedure.
The IDE does not detect that initSomeExampleMembers() instantiates Map, and it therefore notifies me with "*after the constructor execution Map should have a value, define it as nullable?*"

I could locally suppress the warning or move the code back to the constructor and find a way to have them extend each other.
But i was wondering: **is there a way for me to annotate that that init() method is instantiating a specific member?** Like an attribute for example

```
class ExampleClass {
    private ImmutableDictionary Map;

    private void initSomeExampleMembers() {
        //Fill Dictionary with 10 default instances of a class
    }
    ExampleClass() {
        initSomeExampleMembers();
    }
    ExampleClass(/*some params*/) {
        //"Example()"
        initSomeExampleMembers();
        //perform operations on Map items..
        //instantiate some more ExampleClass members..
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `MemberNotNullAttribute`:

```
[MemberNotNull(nameof(Map))]
private void initSomeExampleMembers() 
{
    //Fill Dictionary with 10 default instances of a class
}
```

Read more:

- [Attributes for null-state static analysis interpreted by the C# compiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/attributes/nullable-analysis)

Comment: so easy :facepalm:, ty~